# Recorrer la bahía, en un barco

Tags: traducción

I want to say, "we went on a boat trip around the harbour as soon as we arrived".

Is it, "nada más llegar, recorrimos por la bahía, cogiendo un barco" or "dimos un paseo por la bahía en un barco" or "embarcamos en un barco para recorrer por la bahía".
Or variants of any of these?

Comment: So you ask the question and then disappear? I wonder why...

Answer (score 1):

- We went on a boat trip **around the harbour** as soon as we arrived".
- Dimos **una vuelta a la bahía en barco** así que llegamos.

Notice how "around the harbor" becomes dar una vuelta a la bahía.

This is similar to: **swim across the river**

**atravesar o cruzar el rió nadando**

Answer (score 0):

**'as soon as we arrived'** --> 'ni bien llegamos', 'nada más llegamos', 'apenas llegamos', etc.

**'we went on a boat trip'** --> 'fuimos a dar un paseo en velero/bote'

**'around the harbor'** --> 'por el puerto' o 'por los alrededores del puerto' (o quizá 'alrededor del puerto' pero es menos común)

Entonces:

> Apenas llegamos, fuimos a dar un paseo en velero por los alrededores del puerto.

> Fuimos a dar un paseo en velero por los alrededores del puerto apenas llegamos.

O incluso mejor aún:

> Por los alrededores del puerto, en velero fuimos a dar un paseo apenas llegamos.

Comment: a boat is not a velero, that is a sailboat. boat is just barco...